# How to configure Azure Custom Domain for App Service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, subdomain, azure-web-app-service, custom-domain

I bought domain `xyz.com`. I want to have on address `www.xyz.com` landing page, and on `www.app.xyz.com` App Service from Azure.

I did (and it's ok):

```
Azure Active Directory > Custom domain names > Add custom domain
app.xyz.com > added TXT reocord in DNS registry with MS=... > Domain is verified and set as primary
```

[image]

I also created App Service, published app (`app.azurewebsites.net` is working properly) and now comes hard part.

```
App Services > app > Custom domains > Add hostname > www.app.xyz.com
```

I can't confirm domain ownership. What `A` and `TXT` or `CNAME` (or different combination) should I add to DNS registry? I've tried different combination and all were failures.

I used [TUTORIAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain), but still can't Map existing and verified custom domain to App Service.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't confirm domain ownership. What A and TXT or CNAME (or
>   different combination) should I add to DNS registry?

You could add a CNAME record to map a subdomain to the app's default hostname (.azurewebsites.net, where  is the name of your app).
[image]

For the details, you could refer to [Add a CNAME record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#create-the-cname-record).

> I bought domain xyz.com. I want to have on address www.xyz.com landing
>   page, and on www.app.xyz.com App Service from Azure.

Because your root domain is xyz.com, you could add subdomain www.xyz.com, but cannot make it like this www.app.xyz.com.

Comment: As written below "I did (and it's ok):" I did this and domain is verified. I cannot map existing domain to App Service. I used this [TUTORIAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) and somethings wrong. I don't know what records should I add to DNS registry.

Comment: Actually it's working. Just needed some time to let DNS be propagated.